# NgFor not rendering new items added in array in a chrome extension build using angular 11

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ngfor, angular11

I am developing a chrome extension using angular 11. For building the project I have used custom-webpack and provide the entry point to background.ts as suggested in blog: [Link](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575).

```html
<div class="container">
    <span><b>Steps</b></span><br>
    <span *ngFor="let step of steps;">
      {{step}}<br>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am using the above snippet of code in my app component template. Items are getting pushed to steps array at runtime, If I log the steps array in console, I am seeing that items are being pushed to array but not rendered to UI.

Please help me to find out like how I can make use of ngfor in the chrome extension. For developing the extension, I referred to the above said link.